# How to capture img pixel tracking request with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, pixel, tracking

Like Facebook Pixel Helper extension, I want to create a extension to detect my app's img tracking request.

I use `performance.getEntries()` that I can get all information about chrome devtools's network panel. Everything is fine, I can capture all my js, css file requests but none of my img pixel request are detected.

How can I do this? I want to implement a handy tool to detect all img pixel tracking is sent without opening network panel to check.